# Open LDAP - changetype: attribute type undefined

Tags: openldap

I am trying to establish user account locked scenario using OpenLDAP but I see below error while running ldapmodify command:

```
C:\OpenLDAP\ClientTools>ldapmodify.exe -a -x -D dc=maxcrc,dc=com -w secret -f c:\OpenLDAP\ldifdata\usersNames.ldif
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:389
ldap_new_socket: 628
ldap_prepare_socket: 628
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying ::1 389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 628 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
adding new entry "uid=LDAPadmin5,ou=users,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
ldap_add: Undefined attribute type (17)
        additional info: changetype: attribute type undefined
```

Below is the content of policy, slapd.conf and usersNames.ldif files

Policies3.ldif:

```
dn: ou=Policies3,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
ou: Policies1
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies3,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: passwordDefault
sn: passwordDefault
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdCheckQuality: 0
pwdMinAge: 0
pwdMaxAge: 0
pwdMinLength: 8
pwdInHistory: 5
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 0
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdExpireWarning: 0
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdMustChange: FALSE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE

dn: cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies3,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: default
pwdMaxAge: 2592000
pwdExpireWarning: 3600
#pwdInHistory: 0
#pwdCheckQuality: 0
pwdMaxFailure: 5
pwdLockout: TRUE
#pwdLockoutDuration: 0
#pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
#pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdMinLength: 6
#pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

slapd.conf entry pertaining to this policy:

```
include ./schema/ppolicy.schema
moduleload ppolicy.la

#-- Load overlay
overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_default "cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies3,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
```

usersNames.ldif:

```
dn:uid=LDAPadmin5,ou=users,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: LDAPadmin5
ou: LDAPadmin5
sn: LDAPadmin5
uid: LDAPadmin5    
userPassword:LDAPadmin5
changetype: modify
add: pwdPolicySubentry
pwdPolicySubentry: "cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies2,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
memberOf:cn=group7,ou=groups,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
memberOf:cn=group8,ou=groups,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
```

The Policies3 entry is visible on the openldap explorer but can't see the attribute "pwdLockout" under it. And LDAPadmin5 user already exists in the system.

Comment: You are running ldapmodify -a (add), which doesn't work together with "changetype". So leave out one of these.

Answer (score 0):

```
    pwdPolicySubentry: "cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies2,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
```

Typo. You have `Policies2`: that should surely be `Policies3`.

However you don't need to set the `pwdPolicySubentry` to the default. That's already the default. :-|

NB it is customary to use `device` as the `objectClass` of a `pwdPolicy`, not `person`. It isn't a person.

Unclear why the `pwdPolicy` appears twice in the LDIF.